# Get staking rewards for a specific account

Tags: staking, rewards, js, sdk

Wondering what is the best way to get all the rewards for a specific account.
Currently I’m using getInflationReward RPC endpoint but it requires me to call it per epoch so eventually I’m looping from epoch X until the current one. Are there any better ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this iterating is the Right Way :tm: to get rewards for multiple epochs.  Inflation rewards are stored in the first block produced in each epoch.  It will be much lighter to make the `getInflationReward` call multiple times than to make `getBlock` calls multiple times and do the rewards entry lookup yourself